# How do I add a new attribute to "sumo" and "veins"?

Tags: veins, sumo

I'm a beginner.

I'm trying to research how the behavior of a vehicle changes if you set an estimated time of arrival for each vehicle using sumo and veins, and drive according to that time.

Of course, I think it would be difficult to implement this without traffic conditions and a smart navigation system, but I'm thinking of giving it a try.

Now, when I implement it, I want to add an attribute to  that is not provided in sumo.

I checked the sumo file and it seems to be set in the C++ file, but I couldn't find where I should add it.

Also, I think I need to make some changes to the veins to process the data after adding it in sumo, where can I look to learn more?

Here are the tools I'm using

sumo (1.8.0) veins (5.1) omnet++ (5.6.2)

I am sorry, but I would appreciate it if someone could push this for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add arbitrary attributes to vehicles, this can be done using what SUMO calls "Generic Parameters". See https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v1_8_0/docs/web/docs/Simulation/GenericParameters.md for a quick explanation, see https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L167 for a way to access them from OMNeT++.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

Thanks to you, I understand how to add generic parameters and access them from veins.

So I have one more question

<vType id="typeWE" accel="1.0" decel="1.0" sigma="0.5" length="5" minGap="2.5" maxSpeed="10.00" />.

I know that the above is written in xml format on sumo, but I would like to add "Estimated time of arrival" to this attribute.

This attribute is not provided in sumo.

If I want to add a new attribute, how do I write the behavior in veins or sumo?